# What exactly are terms in ADS?

Tags: ads

I have been using them to simulate my s-parameter tests, but I'm not sure what they are exactly. Are they simply some impedance that simulates an infinite transmission line?

Comment: Show a schematic, or a screenshot of the ADS window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They affect the circuit exactly as if they were 50 ohm resistors (or whatever impedance you specify). This is the same effect an infinitely long 50-ohm characteristic impedance transmission line would have on the circuit.

They also tell the program where to calculate output signals when doing S-parameter simulations.

They might also (I don't remember this detail) also be used to generate stimulus signals for S-parameter simulations, (For example, so you not only get the \$S_{21}\$ but also get \$S_{12}\$) but if you want this behavior it would be more clear to use a Port device than a Term.

Comment: You are correct, they are also used to generate stimulus for the s parameter simulation.